# How to create a function in Matlab or Mathcad for combination of all elements betweeen three sets

Tags: matlab, mathcad

I have a problem with certain issue. So, I have a three sets with four elements, e.g.:

```
[r11, r12, r13, r14]
[r21, r22, r23, r24]
[r31, r32, r33, r34]
```

I need all combination between these elements. But always each of this elements in particular sets must be in the same place:

```
1. r11  r21 r31
2. r11  r21 r32
       .
       .
       .
n. r14  r24 r34
```

How can I do that in Matlab or Mathcad?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming sets `S1`, `S2`, `S3` where `S1` is your `[r11, r12, r13, r14]`:

```
[A,B,C] = ndgrid(S3, S2, S1);
[C(:), B(:), A(:)]
```

For example input:

```
S1 = [1,2];
S2 = [10,20];
S3 = [100,200,300];
```

results in:

```
ans =

     1    10   100
     1    10   200
     1    10   300
     1    20   100
     1    20   200
     1    20   300
     2    10   100
     2    10   200
     2    10   300
     2    20   100
     2    20   200
     2    20   300
```

Comment: @user3770989 I suggest you read through the answers that Amro linked to (i.e. the duplicate), I hadn't seen some of them before.